# SQL LocalDB Open in SQL Mgmt Studio Run Script

Tags: wpf, sql-server, sql-server-ce, ssms, sql-server-2012

I created a new LocalDB database from Visual Studio in my WPF project.  Now I'd like to run a SQL Script to create all the tables in it.  But I can't find how I can open the database with SQL Management Studio?  Is it supposed to work like an .sdf file where you can browse to open the database?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must install SQL Server 2012 Management Studio (Express) as described here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2011/10/27/net-framework-4-now-supports-localdb.aspx - download location: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=29062

Comment: This link may also help folks http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2011/10/28/localdb-where-is-my-database.aspx